# Moving Android's touch screen keyboard "Input Field" off screen while TouchScreenKeyboard is open in Unity? (For properly integrated visual designs.)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, touchscreen

In Unity, the `TouchScreenKeyboard` in Android is opened by the command `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()`. By default, this opens the keyboard in this fashion, with an `inputField` attached to the top of the keyboard managed by Android:

[image]

The problem is this blocks off part of the screen display (white bar across the bottom covering the submit button and integrated test app text field). This prevents a graphically integrated usage of the keyboard. Filling out forms or app page integrated input fields like I am using now to post this thread is not possible with any normal appearance as everything must also simultaneously go into the visible `inputField` at the bottom.

This is meant to be fixed in Unity with a static command of `TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true` which then [according to Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-hideInput.html) moves the `inputField` component off screen:

> Android: There is no reliable way of hiding input field. Unity provides this property which, when you enable it, renders the input field outside of the screen. This gives the illusion of a hidden input field.

The problem is this function is currently broken as described [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/touchscreenkeyboard-hideinput-triggers-numerous-errors-breaks-functions-in-current-android-unity.1303749/). While the input field is moved off screen and hidden, there are still autocomplete lines showing up in the "hidden zone" and clicks in this zone are still being blocked by Android.

Unity has acknowledged the problem and that their function is broken. However, they have stated they have no intention to fix it as noted in that thread. They also have not made their function public so I am not sure how it works.

I am wondering if anyone can explain or provide any suggestions for how such a function could be created to move any automatic Android "input field" off screen from Unity.

As an example, here is an Android keyboard height monitoring function for Unity that may show how Android objects are accessible from Unity:

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
     
    public sealed class SoftKeyboardHelper : MonoBehaviour //MonoBehaviour is class that runs Update() every frame when attached to an enabled "GameObject" in Unity
    {
        public event Action<int> KeyboardHeightChanged;
     
        private void Start()
        {
            TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true; //the command that should work but is broken currently
        }
     
        int _kbHeight = 0;
     
        private void Update() //run every frame update in Unity
        {
            var h = GetHeight();
            if (_kbHeight != h)
            {
                KeyboardHeightChanged?.Invoke(h);
                _kbHeight = h;
            }
        }
     
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        private AndroidJavaClass _unity;
        private AndroidJavaObject _view;
        private AndroidJavaObject _rect;
     
        private int GetHeight()
        {
            if (!TouchScreenKeyboard.visible) return 0;
     
            _view.Call("getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame", _rect);
            return Screen.height - _rect.Call<int>("height");
        }
     
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            _view = _unity
                .GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")
                .Get<AndroidJavaObject>("mUnityPlayer")
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getView");
            _rect = new AndroidJavaObject("android.graphics.Rect");
        }
     
        private void OnDisable()
        {
            _rect?.Dispose();
            _view?.Dispose();
            _unity?.Dispose();
        }
    #else
        private int GetHeight()
        {
            return TouchScreenKeyboard.visible
                ? (int)TouchScreenKeyboard.area.height : 0;
        }
    #endif
    }
```

Can anyone explain how the shown "input field" component of the Android touch screen keyboard works or provide any suggestions for how this might be accessible or moved off screen from within Unity in a similar fashion when the keyboard is opened?

Is there any documentation that explains this?

Furthermore, how is the touch screen keyboard opened in Android without the "input field" for example if I click a search or password bar within a webpage? Is there any clear reason why it would be necessary for the "input field" to be opened and unavoidable in Unity when the `TouchScreenKeyboard` is activated as they suggest in the Unity documentation?

I either must find another way to open the Android touch screen keyboard manually without this input field activating or must rebuild this function from the ground up to move the input field off screen and then fix it.

Thanks for any help, guidance, or resources that may lead in the right direction.